# How to remove a record from Spark DataSet

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am creating a DataSet like this :

```
SparkSession spark = JavaSparkSessionSingleton.getInstance(javaStreamingContext.sparkContext().getConf());
Dataset<Row> journyDF = spark.createDataFrame(journyDataJavaRDD, JournyData.class);
```

"journyDF" has a column "longitude". If the value of that column is 0 then I want to remove that row from "journyDF". (Skip the row from further processing)

Is there a method which can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would appear to be `Dataset.filter()`, so something like

```
Dataset<Row> journyDF = spark.createDataFrame(journyDataJavaRDD, JournyData.class).filter($"longitude" != 0);
```

or perhaps

```
[...].filter(col("longitude").notEqual(0));
```

(You don't specify the type of the column, so you may need to adjust this.)